# Voltage measurement

Tags: voltage, resistors, voltage-measurement

With the 100ohm resistor sitting between my 12V power supply and my device it doesn't spin (it's a hard disk). I also tried to measure the voltage drop with a multimeter to no avail. It always shows the original 12V. What did I missed?

Comment: Schematic? Explanations of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why did you put a resistor between your supply and your hard disk?

Comment: Trying to measure the current consumption ? A typical harddisk consumes upto 0.5A on 12 V, 0.5A x 100 ohms = 50 Volts ! Your resistor is too high ! Try 0.1 ohm: 0.5A x 0.1 ohm = 0.05V so that will give the harddisk 12 - 0.05 = 11.95 V, that will be enough for it to spin. But why do you not simply use the current measuring function of the multimeter ?

Answer (score 2):

With 100 ohms in series with the 12V supply (why are you doing this?), you're basically strangling the HDD of voltage supply, so you will measure most of that 12V across the 100 ohm resistor.

If you're trying to measure current into the HDD's 12V rail, then try 100 *milli*ohms, and then go measuring millivolts with your multimeter, apply Ohm's Law to calculate current.

Comment: Yes, it's 1000 times too high, assuming your purpose is to measure the current drawn by the HDD. What is a "low noise adapter" - what is the context here?

Comment: You can use a resistor to make a fan go slower, but the electronics in a HDD will respond very differently to a fan.  Why are you wanting to put a series resistance on the HDD's 12V rail?

Comment: lol - so a 'low noise adapter' is just a series resistor to make the fan spin slower ... I see they make 'ultra low noise adapters' too - higher value resistor? ;)

Comment: @Phpdevpad Thank you for my laugh of the day.  I bet if you put 12V in, it will spin faster.